# INSERT results in DUPLICATE ENTRY '0' FOR KEY PRIMARY

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am using a simple php script to insert data into database but it's failing. The query just doesn't become successful without showing a single error which is why I am unable to figure out the problem. Some expert here help me please.

```
echo $name." ".$email." ".$pass." ".$phone." ".$area." ".$specialization." ".$city." ".$latitude." ".$longitude;
```

The result of echo is normal - without any null elements.

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO users (name, email, pass, phone, area, specialization, hospital, city, latitude, longitude) 
                         VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$pass', '$phone', '$area', '$specialization', '$hospital', '$city', '$latitude', '$longitude') ");

if ($query) {
                echo "Status: Registeration Successful!";

                // creating directory for user and storing dummy profile picture
                //mkdir('../profiles/'.$email_trim, 0777);
                //$result_copy = copy("img/dp.jpg.jpg", "../profiles/".$email_trim."/dp.jpg.jpg");
} else {
    echo "Status: Err";
}
```

This "Status: Err" is always printed. I don't know why.

P.S I have double checked the database the field labels are fine.

UPDATE 1:

I added the

```
die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

statement and it says "DUPLICATE ENTRY '0' FOR KEY PRIMARY'.

PROBLEM AND SOLUTION:

The issue was that I had an 'id' field which was primary key of the table but it was not set to AUTO_INCREMENT. So, whenever I tried to insert a new record, I was actually inserting entries with duplicate PKs which was the issue. I change it to AUTO_INCREMENT and it solved the problem.

Comment: Call `mysqli_error($conn)` to find out what the error is

Comment: `without showing a single error` - i.e. you get the `Status: Registeration Successful!` output?

Comment: also check `mysqli_connect_errno()` before the call

Comment: note you are vulnerable to sql injections.  If you switch to prepared statements, you will both be more secure and you won't need to worry about a) escaping your variables, and b) remembering when to throw quotes around them

Comment: add die(mysqli_error($conn)); in else condition to check errors

Comment: @VolkerK No. No MySQL error is thrown like the one is thrown when your credentials are wrong or when you are accessing a field that doesn't exist.

Comment: echo "INSERT INTO..."; and, print this echo statement directly/manually to phpmyadmin to see the error

Comment: The add `auto_increment` to your primary key definition ;) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: Regarding `DUPLICATE ENTRY '0' FOR KEY PRIMARY`: Please add the table definition (prepferably in the form of a valid `CREATE TABLE ...` statement, `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...` will give you that) to your question text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you try to insert a new element with a PK = 0, but there is already a record with this key !
What is the primary key of your table ? Do you use an "id" field which is not shown in your insert statement ? Is this field AUTO_INCREMENT ?

Comment: It wasn't. But I have not changed it to AUTO_INCREMENT and the problem has been solved. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It would be helpful to see the structure of your 'users' table.

Wild guess: looks like you may have defined an "id" column (or with whatever other name) which is primary key with default value "0", but it's not auto increment. That way you can insert 1 row and it will get "0" as "id" column's value, but you cannot insert another row because it will also try to use default value "0", which cannot happen as primary key has to be unique.

If that is the case, then please alter users table and make sure that the primary key column is also 'auto increment'.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the proper error by adding below mentioned code inside **else**:

```
echo mysqli_errno($conn) . '----' . mysqli_error($conn);
```

Comment: Please have a look at the update I made to the question.

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `email`, `pass`, `phone`, `area`, `specialization`, `hospital`, `city`, `latitude`, `longitude`) 
                     VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$pass', '$phone', '$area', '$specialization', '$hospital', '$city', '$latitude', '$longitude') ");
```

use **`** Tick maybe because there's some reserved word in your fields.

Comment: @Cartoon can you check your `$conn`?

Comment: @ShiguriAnemone As an FYI `name` is not a reserved word; it is a keyword and still may be use without backticks. It won't solve the issue. See the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html (note that it does not have an "R" next to it)

Comment: Then you might want to check the manual above;  this answer is not helpful

Comment: @nomistic I'm on it... Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO `users` (`name`, `email`, `pass`, `phone`, `area`, `specialization`, `hospital`, `city`, `latitude`, `longitude`) 
                 VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$pass', '$phone', '$area', '$specialization', '$hospital', '$city', '$latitude', '$longitude') ") or die(mysqli_error());
```

Comment: backticks are unnecessary and there is no explanation as to why this answer would work

Answer (score -2):

I think you doubled your close parenthesis and do not put $conn inside the query..

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (name, email, pass, phone, area, specialization, hospital, city, latitude, longitude) 
                         VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$pass', '$phone', '$area', '$specialization', '$hospital', '$city', '$latitude', '$longitude')";
mysqli_query($query, $conn);
```

Something like this. I hope this helps

Comment: Because a) it doesn't answers the question and b) two other people came up with the same answer before you. Your answer is wrong and duplicate.